# Why am I getting a 'page not found' error when clicking on 'forgot password' in the WordPress admin login page?

Tags: wordpress

When I tab on forgot password in login page wordpress site as admin it goes to the site whith header and footer and showes page not found. what is problem?

I disable plugins and check which one is cause of error but nothing changed!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.